# How to call ghostscript from java with whitespaces in file paths

Tags: java, escaping, whitespace, ghostscript

Recently I found myself having to launch the ghostscript command from java, in both linux and windows environments, with whitespaces in input/output filenames. An example of the command follows:

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pnggray -r300 -sOutputFile=/home/nic/tomcat/6.0.33 with spaces/temp/Thread-11/img-%03d.png /home/nic/tomcat/6.0.33 with spaces/temp/tmpfile.tmp
```

*The gs gets replaced by gswin32 on windows, given that ghostscript is in the Path.*

I quickly realized that I had to escape the file names in some manner, so the first thing I've done was to enclose them between double quotes. This worked on windows, but not on linux: on linux I've tried the double quotes enclosing and also escaping whitespaces with backslashes, but without success.

For launching the command I'm using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);`, passing one single string. I found the following question [getting ghostscript to take in files with spaces in their name (like something in "my documents")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804646/getting-ghostscript-to-take-in-files-with-spaces-in-their-name-like-something-i) but:

- I desired to extend it also for linux;
- I found that double quoting works for me, differently than how it's pointed out there.

I would like to understand this thing once per all: can you help me to do this?

Here follows a summary of my attempts, per SO.

### Windows

Enclosing file names in double quotes worked for me:

```
gswin32 -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pnggray -r300 -sOutputFile="C:\Program Files\tomcat 6.0.33 with spaces\temp\Thread-11\img-%03d.png" "C:\Program Files\tomcat 6.0.33 with spaces\temp\tmpfile.tmp"
```

### Linux

Tried to enclose file names in double quotes

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pnggray -r300 -sOutputFile="/home/nic/tomcat/6.0.33 with spaces/temp/Thread-11/img-%03d.png" "/home/nic/tomcat/6.0.33 with spaces/temp/tmpfile.tmp"
```

Tried to escape white space with backslash

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pnggray -r300 -sOutputFile=/home/nic/tomcat/6.0.33\ with\ spaces/temp/Thread-11/img-%03d.png /home/nic/tomcat/6.0.33\ with\ spaces/temp/tmpfile.tmp
```

Tried both together

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pnggray -r300 -sOutputFile="/home/nic/tomcat/6.0.33\ with\ spaces/temp/Thread-11/img-%03d.png" "/home/nic/tomcat/6.0.33\ with\ spaces/temp/tmpfile.tmp"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use [Runtime.exec(String[] args)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) which takes multiple arguments ? This variant is designed to avoid you having to escape such arguments. Since the arguments are provided separately there's no space-based interpolation required and thus no confusion.

Comment: Tried it as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/a/1804714/1504300, but without success. I will give it again a try

Comment: Definitely works, I was giving it a parameter in a wrong way... Sorry