# Error executing Ghostscript from Java program

Tags: java, ghostscript

I am executing a ghostscript command in a JUnit test and the test finish with error. However when I executed the same command in terminal, the command finished without error.

```
Command: /usr/local/bin/gs -sOutputFile="OUTPUT_PATH" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceGray -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH "INPUT_PATH"
```

I execute the command using the java runtime.

```
Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

int exitValue = pr.waitFor();

if (exitValue != 0) {
   ....
}
```

The error from execution.

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.21: **** Could not open the file "OUTPUT_PATH" .
```

Comment: Clearly the difference is the environment, not GS. I would hazard a guess that the current working directory when you execute the command from Java is not writeable (or at least not for the current user). This would mean that Ghostscript can't open the output file for writing. Try specifying a complete path and output file to a directory where you know for sure the Java thing is allowed to write. The other possibility is that the file is already present and open by another application. Again writing to a different (fully qualified) location should prevent that, as long as you are careful.

Comment: Thank you @KenS, I use a full path to the file in the JUnit test. For example I use the target folder on eclipse to write the file.

`Paths.get("target", "GRAYSCALE_TEST.pdf");`

Comment: Well it still seems to me its a problem with the environment. Note that I know nothing about Java, so your Eclipse line tells me nothing I'm afraid. Clearly Ghostscript is working (because it works in the shell). The difference must be in the environment surrounding it. The error is pretty clear; Ghostscript can't open the file. There are two possible reasons, firstly the C run-time fopen() using "wb" failed, secondly you are outputting to something other than a file (eg %stdout%") and that fails. For this reason it would be **much** better to quote the actual paths, in full, so I could tell.

Comment: Quoting the full back channel transcript might help too, its certainly useful to see it.

Comment: Thank you for all @KenS, I found the problem in the Java call. I was adding a double quote to file path to avoid problems with whitespace. I found the solution reading the answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799686/how-to-call-ghostscript-from-java-with-whitespaces-in-file-paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by double quotes of output path when building the command.